# Why sometimes I can't use a term in a dart file while in other dart files I can use this term?

Tags: flutter

Please see the attached pictures:
Look I can't use it in withoutregister dart file: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5NAG.png)

I can use it in main dart: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhP5b.png), but in the last picture actually the bottom navigation bar didn't show up or because I haven't register successfully.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`bottomNavigationBar` is part of Scaffold. So you can use it inside scaffold. but on 1st images you are trying to use it inside `AppBar`

for more

- [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)
- [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to `AppBar`!

```
Scaffold(
   bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[...],            
   ),
   body: ...
),
```